# Node server stops accepting connections after streaming large response

Tags: node.js, http, mongoose, stream, cursor

Using Node, Express, MongoDB, and Mongoose, I'm trying to stream a potentially large number of objects (100K+) to a client.

This works fine for a few thousand records. However, for 100K+ records, the request completes successfully after about a minute, *but all subsequent requests to the server hang and I need to restart the server*. No errors are visible.

Thoughts on what might be happening? Thoughts on the best way to debug?

Here's my code:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
res.write('{"meta":{"code":200},"objects":[');

Object
  .find({ foo: 'bar' })
  .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
  .lean()
  .cursor()
  .on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.end();
  })
  .on('data', function (object) {
    if (!first)
      res.write(',');
    else  
      first = false;

    res.write(JSON.stringify(object));
  })
  .on('close', function () {
    res.end(']}');
  });
```

**Edit:**

After a few minutes of waiting, I'll see the following error and subsequent requests start working again. So, I suspect it has something to do with not closing connections properly.

```
Error: write after end
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:443:15)
    at QueryCursor.<anonymous> (<redacted>/server/models/object.js:431:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at QueryCursor.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at QueryCursor.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:381:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:761:34)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:433:3)
    at wrapped (<redacted>/node_modules/newrelic/lib/transaction/tracer/index.js:183:28)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:71:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

**Edit 2:**

I never fully got to the bottom of this, but I suspect that the server was choking attempting to JSON serialize a huge number of records. I ended up going with a different solution, making multiple paged requests from the client instead of loading the records all at once. See below.

Comment: There's potentially a lot of stuff going on in here. Do you have any way of knowing where it might jam up? A little logging spiked in to the various steps might help determine where the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, I've sprinkled in some logging. Part of the challenge is that the request does successfully complete. It's just subsequent requests that don't work, and I'm not sure why. It's like the server doesn't even accept the connection.

Comment: If you jam up the main event loop for some reason that's the behaviour you're going to see, the whole app stops accepting connections or producing output. It's possible you have some really crazy self-referential data structure that the JSON stringifier cannot cope with, though it is supposed to warn you if that's the case.

Comment: I never fully got to the bottom of this, but I suspect that the server was choking attempting to JSON serialize a huge number of records. I ended up going with a different solution, making multiple paged requests from the client instead of loading the records all at once.

Comment: If you need to stream a lot of data it might make sense to go that way. Also an option: Streaming over Websocket or Socket.io type interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up avoiding this issue by making multiple paged requests from the client instead of loading the records all at once. This reduces strain on the server and the database and also allows me to show a progress indicator on the client.